# How to limit laptop integrated webcam's field of view?

Tags: windows, webcam, conferencing

**What I have:**

- In my line of work, we make extensive use of video meetings.
- We all use the laptop's integrated webcam, and a variety of video apps - mostly MS Teams and Webex - on Windows 11.
- The camera sees a wide angle, around 80 degrees. That's not just my head but almost down to my keyboard, as well as the entire room. This would be fine for a conference room with several people in the frame, but it's only me, plus all the background to my sides that I don't want to show.
- If I want to show only my head, I would have to be ~20 centimeters from the lens, which is quite ridiculous.
- I know that the meeting applications can insert a virtual background, and I use this, but that's not what I am asking for here.

**What I want:**

- I want the camera to see a narrower part of the room. I want it to see only my head.
- I want to set the field of view to ~20 degrees.
- I know there's no setting in MS Teams, or in Webex, that does this.
- Can the webcam field of view be limited to "square" or "portrait" instead of this ridiculous "widescreen"?
- Is there a piece of software that would go between the camera and the meeting application, which could control what the meeting application sees? Maybe even one that can track where I am and only show that?

Comment: My Logitech came with such a piece of software (no longer compatible with W11 though) so it's definitely possible. I know of nothing except OBS now though that would help

Comment: Tape a toilet roll tube in front of the camera - so the camera is looking down the tube - done...

Answer (score 0):

Your question have two parts, hardware and software:

**Hardware** - most web cams have fixed lens so you can't change the field of view of the lens and computer. There are some zoom/vario lens but most of them have this function manual. Here is [example](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Mermaid-2592X1944-Aluminium-Conference-Operating/dp/B088STZ353), [example2](https://www.amazon.com.au/ELP-Adjustable-Windows-Android-USBFHD01M-SFV/dp/B07PD2QHXY).

**Software** - I am not aware of such software but you can ask your question [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (where IMHO will be more appropriate)

Answer (score 0):

There are various apps that can "zoom" in digitally, i.e., just use a subset of the sensor's pixels, **if** the physical webcam supports that.

- [Windows Camera app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-the-camera-app-ea40b69f-be6a-840e-9c8c-1fd6eea97c22) can change aspect ratio, allowing cutoff of horizontal *or* vertical portions.

  [image: Windows Camera app]
- The free third-party [Webcam Settings Tool (Webcam Einstellungen Tool für Windows)](https://ekiwi-blog.de/downloads/) enable direct control of cameras that implement a *zoom* setting.

  [image: Webcam Settings Tool]
- Nexigo and Logitech cameras, for example, can use their own software to zoom in.

Though set in one application, e.g., *Camera*, these settings persist for other apps to use, ** unless that application sets other values**.

Another alternative is to get an inexpensive telephoto adapter for a *fixed lens camera* or mobile phone (not a telephoto *lens*), and attach it to the webcam's lens.